# Java: Selective comparison of two sets

Tags: java, comparison, set

I am writing a lot of unit tests that do similar things with but with different classes.

I want to compare Sets of the same class.  The class specifies an id property.  In set A this property is all null.  In Set B this property is set.  (Set B has been persisted to a database and uids have been populated).

For my unit test I want to make sure that Set A matches Set B and I obviously don't want it to look at the id field.

What is the most efficient, clean and DRY way of doing this?

Comment: Seriously, people, what's with the close/down votes? Maybe it's not a perfect question, but first ask the guy to augment/rephrase instead of bashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, compare two sets' sizes, if they're not equal, test fails.

For a non-trivial case, ddefine a `java.util.Comparator` for set elements, sort both according to this comparator (you can include/omit the property by which you don't want to compare). Then iterate over both sets, comparing elements based on your rules (different from the ones defined by the comparator, if I understand correctly your point).

I assume you already have your `equals` and `hashCode` methods properly defined and don't want to change them for the sake of the test.

Comment: I selected this answer because MaDa is quite correct in their assumption that I do not want to alter the classes under test for the sake of testing (i.e. defining different equals and hashCode methods)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the hashCode() and equals() method of the classes where you should not include the id field in both the method then the equals method Set will work how you want.

for Example,

```
class  Test{

int id;
String name;
String other;
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((other == null) ? 0 : other.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Test other = (Test) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (this.other == null) {
        if (other.other != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!this.other.equals(other.other))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Now the Test class object are not dependent on ID. You can very easily generate the equlas and hashCode method using a IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `equals()` & `hashCode()` method in your class and then use `removeAll()` method to remove all the elements from `Set B`. Post this, if the set is empty, then they match, else they don't.

Note that the overridden methods should have the logic, which doesn't involve`id`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison for duplicate items logic is achieved in Java using the **equals()** method.

> myString.equals("compare this");

When you need to compare objects of your custome types, you have to override equals method.

```
Student student1=new Student();
Student student2=new Student();
student1.equals(student2);
```

But be careful when you override equals() method. You need to provide some basis of comparison based on some unique ids. For instance, the following implementation uses the Roll number as a unique id for comparison

```
public class Student {

  private int rollNo;
  private String name;
  private String address;


    // Getters and Setters

@Override
  public int hashCode() {
   // Overide this only when you use Hashing implementations
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      System.out.println("Not Equal due to NULL");
      return false;
    }
    if (this == obj) {
      System.out.println("Equals due to same reference");
      return true;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      System.out.println("Different Type");
      return false;
    }
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (rollNo == other.rollNo) {
      System.out.println("RollNo " + rollNo + " EQUALS " + other.rollNo);
      return true;
    }
    if (rollNo != other.rollNo) {
      System.out.println("RollNo " + rollNo + " NOT EQUALS " + other.rollNo);
      return false;
    }
    System.out.println("Default is FALSE");
    return false;
  }

}
```